# "No Heroku apps are configured error" on Heroku Sans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-san

I am configuring [heroku_san](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san) for deploying Rails to Heroku. When I run any rake task it creates, I keep getting this error:

rake production deploy

No heroku apps are configured. Run:
          rails generate heroku:config

I know that there are Heroku apps because I can see them when I run `heroku list`. What might be happening? Why can't this gem find the Heroku apps?

Comment: What is in your `config/heroku.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the gem was looking for a file called `~/.heroku/credentials`. I did not have it. So I created that and added my user email and password separated by a linebreak:

> myemail@gmail.com
>
> herokupassword

Worked like a charm.